# Macro in Excel to Copy/Paste Specific Ranges in Two Workbooks into a New Workbook (More Details Inside)

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I can perhaps better describe what I want by way of example. I have two Excel workbooks. I want to essentially copy one over to a new workbook **as it is** (basic copy/paste of everything), and then copy over a **specific** portion of the other workbook and paste it at the end of the new workbook.

So, there are two input workbooks and one output workbook. And that is how I would like the macro to be structured: There should be a "master" workbook that contains the macro (button) where the two input workbooks are specified by their folder path, and there is an output folder for the new combined workbook (see the very end for example of how I'd like it specified). The first of the input workbooks should have everything in it copied over. Note that this should be dynamic, and should not dictate a specific cell range (as cell ranges could vary). An example of the first input workbook is shown below:

[image: Example of Workbook to be Copied Fully to New Workbook]

Everything is to be copied over. I don't think that's much of an issue. The tricky part (for me) is to then take a specific portion of the second input workbook and copy/paste that to the end of the first input workbook. I am finding this difficult because the second input folder should be selected by a specific header and then everything under that header should be copied (i.e. select header and then CTRL+SHIFT+DOWN). For example:

[image: Second Input Workbook - Copy Everything Below Specific Header]

This should take "Maturity[5,)" (highlighted in yellow) as the header and then select everything under that, copy it, and then paste it to the matching header at the end of the first input workbook (second row, i.e., Row 8, which, by the way, is the format for all workbooks for this: Rows 1:6 are empty, but should stay like that).

Hopefully you're still with me. After this is done, the new (combined) workbook should look something like this:

[image]

Just even getting this far would be extremely helpful. But there is one more issue. By copying over the entirety of the first input workbook, there is an additional header (Row 7; "L-OAS" in the above picture). This header needs to be merged and centered across the range of the new combined workbook, including the second input workbook portion added:

[image: Merge and Center Top Header in New Combined Workbook]

And that's it. Once that header has been merged and centered in the new workbook, the macro should save the new workbook in the output path specified.

Example of input/output paths to be specified:

[image: Input/Output Paths for Macro]

**EDIT: The below is my attempt at doing part (1) -- that is, just copying and pasting the first workbook.**

```
Sub Combine()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
shtOutput1.Visible = xlSheetVisible
shtOutput1.Cells.Clear
Set outputRange = shtOutput1.Cells(1, 1)

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Range("USDInputFile1").Value, False, True)

For Each wsSource In wb1.Worksheets

    If InStr(wsSource.Cells(1, 1).Value, "Bloomberg") > 0 Then

        With wsSource

        wsSource.Copy shtOutput1

                End With
    End If
Next

wb1.Close False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

With Workbooks.Add

    shtOutput1.Copy .Worksheets(1)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each ws In .Worksheets

    Next ws

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    .Close True, ThisWorkbook.Names("OutputFolder").RefersToRange.Value + Application.PathSeparator + "USD Combined Output.xlsx"

End With

shtOutput1.Cells.Clear

shtOutput1.Visible = xlSheetHidden

 
End Sub
```

1. "shtOutput1" is a worksheet in the master workbook (where the macro
   button and file paths are located
2. "USDInputFile1" is a named Cell in the master workbook that leads to
   the file path for the first input workbook (i.e. "wb1" -- "wb2" will
   be the second input workbook)

Comment: What vba code have you tried? Or where are you stuck?

Comment: @PGSystemTester Please see the edit. That will copy and save the first workbook (i.e., copy and paste everything into a new workbook, then save) -- but I'm still struggling with the second part (with the second input workbook)

Answer (score 0):

Lets just take a step back and look at this from a scalability stance.

You don't want a button to combine things because there is a lot to go wrong and a fair bit of babysitting you will have to do VBA wise and on top of that pressing is a button... ppffft that's work...

No what you want is a seamless update where anything added to Maturity 5 or Maturity 10 will automatically update to your output leaving them to just grow on their own untouched downward like Microsoft intended.

1. First lets look at the structure, there is some, they have headers but they are not tables and they both have a common ID Date, So change your bottom most headers to ensure they make sense and are Uniform, Unique and Consistant across all iterations of each table. So Mat5_Total or Mat10_Total etc for however many you have.
2. Insert Tab - Table - Give them proper Shorthand Table names like tblMat10 and tblMat5
3. Lets open a New File and get them in with Data Tab in the ribbon - External Data - Tranform - Little Down arrow on Close an Load and you only want this in the datamodel not loaded to the Spreadsheet So check **Create Connection Only** and **Add this data to the Datamodel**. Uncheck everything else there is no need to clutter your output.
4. Repeat 3 but for Mat10 only when you get to Close an load instead look to the Right and hit the down arrow on **Merge Queries** -  as a new Query .
5. Now a new window will pop up Select the two queries and Join them on their Dates as the ID
6. Now you can close and load to the a sheet.

Give it a spin add some new data to Mat5 or Mat10 and refresh your newly created linking Sheet.

This works for all kinds of data, you can trial this with stocks, shares, CSV, ODBC Connections all sorts of data connections. all you need is a properly formatted infrastructure aka properly formatted tables!

A bonus to this method is if the tables evolve, modifying your Power Query is easy. Just rememeber to go into your connection settings and select refresh on open and if you like set it to refresh every 5 minutes.

7  Optional Bonus - Once this output table has been made it will be compatible with any external programs, because it is a correctly formatted output table.

Comment: I appreciate the response - but I do not want to edit the format of the spreadsheets at all. These are vendor-supplied and need to be in the depicted format for downstream dependencies.

Comment: What is [Staging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-SXLaQGg50) for 10 points...


Jokes aside, what you have done is Extract as parts of ETL (Extract Transform Load)

Transforming Data requires a few parts, Staging is the first part and it's important to get right because as per the above, if you don't stage your data it will become a mess to deal with... see your original post.


So you need to get that into tables. you can do this by taking the original mess and adding a helper sheet, where it just litterally is covered in =Cells with it's own headers.